# Value of \def specified via command line not being properly recognized

Tags: macros, pdftex

I am having difficulty understanding why defining a macro on the command line is being treated differently than if it is specified in the file.

The MWE below allows `\FormattingMode` to be set to `Print` or `Electronic`. If it is set to *any* other value a `\PackageError` is triggerred. This works just fine when the option is specified in the file. So, the following command works fine:

```
 pdflatex "\input{TeX-SE}"
```

However, when I attempt to define the `\FormattingMode` via the command line:

```
pdflatex "\def\FormattingMode{Print}\input{TeX-SE}"
```

I end up with

> ***** 
> ***** Unknown `\FormattingMode`="Print". 
> ***** Valid `\FormattingMode`: "Electronic" or "Print". 
> ***** 
>
> ! Package  Error: Invalid `\FormattingMode`="Print"..

### Code:

```
%\providecommand{\FormattingMode}{Electronic}%
\providecommand{\FormattingMode}{Print}%
\documentclass{article}


%% ----------------------------------------------- start .sty file contents
%% The following is buried in a .sty file, but is added here to simplify the MWE
\newcommand{\FormattingModeElectronic}{Electronic}%
\newcommand{\FormattingModePrint}{Print}%
\AtBeginDocument{% Ensure that a proper mode was provided.
    \ifx\FormattingMode\FormattingModeElectronic
        \typeout{***** Formatting for ELECTRONIC medium}%
    \else
        \ifx\FormattingMode\FormattingModePrint
            \typeout{***** Formatting for PRINT medium}%
        \else
            \typeout{*****}%
            \typeout{***** Unknown \string\FormattingMode="\FormattingMode".}%
            \typeout{***** Valid  \string\FormattingMode: "\FormattingModeElectronic" or "\FormattingModePrint".}%
            \typeout{*****}%
            \PackageError{}{Invalid \string\FormattingMode="\FormattingMode".}{}%
        \fi
    \fi
}%
%% ----------------------------------------------- end .sty file contents

\begin{document}
some content formatted for \textbf{\FormattingMode} media
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about this?  Match your `\def`s and `\newcommand`s: i.e., if you use `\newcommand\FormattingModePrint{Print}` *in* the file, use `pdflatex "\newcommand\FormattingMode{Print}\input{TeX-SE}"` on the command line, or use `\def` in both cases....

Comment: @jon: Does that actually work for you? I did a quick test and it does not seem to -- although have to admit that I am on a conference call so am a bit distracted so perhaps I missed something.

Comment: It did, though I had no time to figure out why before going to bed. I had removed the braces in my test and I wasn't sure if that would matter.  (I also figured one or more of the usual suspects would be better able to explain anyway...)

Comment: @jon: Yeah, the _usual suspects_ have saved me sooooo many times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}`, the command `\show\foo` will tell you

```
> \foo=\long macro:
->bar.
```

When you say `\def{\FOO}{bar}` you get

```
> \FOO=macro:
->bar.
```

Then `\ifx\foo\FOO` would evaluate to false, because one macro is long and the other one isn't.

If you plan to use `\def` in the command line, use `\newcommand*` which doesn't make `\long` macros.

From the TeXbook, page 210:

> • `\ifx`〈token<sub>1</sub>〉〈token<sub>2</sub>〉 (test if tokens agree)
>   In this case, TeX does *not* expand control sequences when it looks at the two tokens. The condition is true if (a) the two tokens are not macros, and they both represent the same (character code, category code) pair or the same TeX primitive or the same `\font` or `\chardef` or `\countdef`, etc.; or if (b) the two tokens are macros, and they both have the same status with respect to `\long` and `\outer`, and they both have the same parameters and “top level” expansion. For example, after
>   `\def\a{\c}| |\def\b{\d}| |\def\c{\e}| |\def\d{\e}| |\def\e{A}|`, an
>   `\ifx` test will find `\c` and `\d` equal, but not `\a` and `\b`, nor `\d`
>   and `\e`, nor any other combinations of `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\d`, `\e`.